# After sharing via WhatsApp, webview shows a blank screen

Tags: android, cordova, webview, phonegap-plugins

I've built an app using Cordova, which is an webview of my responsive website. My problem is: My website has a button to share a link via WhatsApp, and after I share the link my webview shows a white screen written "chromewebdata".
[image: error]

my code:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    ref = window.open("http://m.estadao.com.br/?load-all=true", "_blank", "location=no", "toolbar=no", "closebuttoncaption=a", "EnableViewPortScale=no");
            
            navigator.notification.activityStart("", "Carregando...");
            setTimeout(function(){
                navigator.notification.activityStop();
            }, 5000);
            
            urlChanged = function(event){
                if(event.url.startsWith("whatsapp://")){
                    window.open.(event.url, "_system");
                    return;
                }
            }
            browser.addEventListener("laodstart", urlChanged, false);

            ref.addEventListener('exit', function () {
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            });
                
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but there's at least a typo in this line: `browser.addEventListener("laodstart", urlChanged, false);`

Comment: @Buddy Wasn't it :P tks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
        urlChanged = function(event){
            if(event.url.startsWith("http://whatsapp://")){
                window.open.(event.url, "_system");
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm confused. Can you clarify why you believe this would work? The only change you made is to prefix the `startsWith()` URL with `http://`. Yet, presumably, their WhatsApp links will start with `whatsapp://` not `http://whatsapp://`. If so, this will break that logic. But, regardless, it doesn't appear to do anything to address the specific problem they're reporting.